# Provided implicit reader/writer for case class not found

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I'm trying to write a nice generic persistence service with one implementation for mongo using Reactive Mongo and I'm struggling with providing the implicit reader/writer for my record class children. Here's the code.

First the base record class (each persisted record must implement it.

```
abstract class Record {
  val _id: BSONObjectID = BSONObjectID.generate()
}
```

Second one record child case class (very simple) with its writer/reader (both possible way to do it, Macros vs custom in comment)

```
case class TestRecord() extends Record {}
  object TestRecord {
//    implicit object TestRecordWriter extends BSONDocumentWriter[TestRecord] {
//      def write(testRecord: TestRecord): BSONDocument = BSONDocument()
//    }
//
//    implicit object TestRecordReader extends BSONDocumentReader[TestRecord] {
//      def read(doc: BSONDocument): TestRecord = TestRecord()
//    }

    implicit def reader = Macros.reader[TestRecord]
    implicit def writer = Macros.writer[TestRecord]
  }
```

And then the service itself

```
class MongoPersistenceService[R <: Record] @Inject()()
                                                    (implicit ec: ExecutionContext, tag: ClassTag[R]) {

  val collectionName: String = tag.runtimeClass.getSimpleName

  def db: Future[DefaultDB] = MongoConnectionWrapper.getMongoConnection("mongodb://127.0.0.1", "27017")
                              .flatMap(_.database("testDb"))

  def collection: Future[BSONCollection] = db.map(_.collection(collectionName))

  def persist(record: R): Future[Unit] = {
    collection.flatMap(_.insert(record)).map(_ => {})
  }

  def read(id: BSONObjectID): Future[R] = {
    for {
      coll <- collection
      record <- coll.find(BSONDocument("_id" -> id)).one[R].mapTo[R]
    } yield record
  }
}
```

And here's my failing test:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

class MongoPersistenceServiceSpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfter {
  val persistenceService = new MongoPersistenceService[TestRecord]()

    "persist" when {
      "called" should {
        "succeeds when passing a not persisted record" in {
          val testRecord = TestRecord()

          persistenceService.persist(testRecord)

          val persistedRecord = Await.result(persistenceService.read(testRecord._id), Duration(1000, "millis"))
        assert(persistedRecord.eq(testRecord))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Compiler complains with following messages:

```
Error:(33, 32) could not find implicit value for parameter writer: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentWriter[R]
  collection.flatMap(_.insert(record)).map(_ => {})

Error:(33, 32) not enough arguments for method insert: (implicit writer: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentWriter[R], implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[reactivemongo.api.commands.WriteResult].
  Unspecified value parameters writer, ec.
    collection.flatMap(_.insert(record)).map(_ => {})

Error:(39, 57) could not find implicit value for parameter reader: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[R]
  record <- coll.find(BSONDocument("_id" -> id)).one[R].mapTo[R]

Error:(39, 57) not enough arguments for method one: (implicit reader: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[R], implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[Option[R]].
  Unspecified value parameters reader, ec.
    record <- coll.find(BSONDocument("_id" -> id)).one[R].mapTo[R]
```

Anybody has a idea what I might be missing?
I'm still new to scala so help me find the issue in here.

I already tried writing custom BSONWriter/BSONReader instead of the BSONDocumentWriter/BSONDocumentReader provided here without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, Scala doesn't search everywhere throughout your code for implicits. They need to be brought into scope, either through imports, passing them as parameters, or, as I would suggest here, [through a context bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/context-bounds):

```
class MongoPersistenceService[R <: Record : BSONDocumentReader : BSONDocumentWriter]
```

This is a kind of short hand for (a) requiring that an implicit `BSONDocumentReader[R]` (and writer) can be found at the time that the class is constructed with a specific `R`, and (b) bringing those implicits into scope within the class's implementation so they can be implicitly passed to other methods like `insert`.

In order to fulfill that new requirement (a) you may have to `import TestRecord._` within your test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I learned one more thing about scala today!

Answer (score 1):

Your `persist` function doesn't have access to the fact that you have defined those implicit functions.  The signature should be something like this:

```
def persist(record: R)(implicit def writer: BSONDocumentWriter[R]): Future[Unit]
```

And wherever you call `persist` and pass a `TestRecord` make sure that the implicit functions are in scope.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is also a valid answer (tried it and worked as the other one) but I personally prefer the first one since I write it once and only once at class declaration and not every method in the class. But both are working.